# Navigate to the desired page from login page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say a user wants to see a page that needs authentication. After a successful login, I want user to be redirected to the page he/she wanted to see in the first place.

This is the login component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../actions';
import validator from 'validator';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  renderField(field) {
      const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;
      const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger':''}`;
      return (
        <div className={className}>
          <label>{field.label}</label>
          <input className="form-control"
            type="text"
            {...field.input}
          />
          <div className="text-help">
            {touched ? error:''}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const { history } = this.props;
    this.props.loginUser(values, ({status, headers}) => {
      if (status === 200) {
        const { authorization } = headers;
        localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', authorization);
        history.push("/"); //HERE ????
      }
    });
  }

  render() {

    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          name="username"
          label="Username"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Enter</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
   //.....
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form:'LoginForm'
})(
  connect(null, { loginUser })(LoginForm)
);
```

I tried `history.goBack()` but apparently it doesn't redirect to the path user wanted to access before getting to the login page. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong!

1. You should use from [react life cycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and send a request to
   backend if you get user info you can redirect to index route.
2. You should user from `withRouter` to access to `history.push()`
   method.

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';`

```
@withRouter

class LoginForm extends Component {

 ** DidMount because it's client side and you reading the token from window ojbect **
  componentDidMount() {
   I don't know you use which library to handle request...
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt_token');
    if (token) {
      axios.get('/user/profile', {
        header: {
          token
        }
      })
    .then((response) => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // 401 Unauthorized
    });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I already have access to history object. I'm looking for a way to go back to the URL by which user got to the login form.